# php5enmod returns command not found

Tags: 12.04, php

I've tried a number of guides on this issue, but so far I cannot get `php5enmod mcrypt` to work.

```
Ubuntu 12.04
PHP 5.3.10
```

Here is the output ls of `/etc/php5/conf.d` and `/etc/php5/mods-available`

https://privatepaste.com/35aee04356

```
root:~# sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo: php5enmod: command not found
root:~#
```

Comment: What's the exact error you have, please ?

Comment: command not found is the exact error

Comment: Please, be more specific. The error is simply command not found, without any other string? Could you copy/paste the string and update your question?

Comment: updated the 1st post    'root:~# sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo: php5enmod: command not found
root:~#'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`php5enmod` was introduced in Debian in version `5.4.0~rc6-2` of the package `php5` (see the [changelog](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/p/php5/php5_5.4.45-0+deb7u2_changelog), Ctrl+F is your friend). Since Ubuntu packages are imported from Debian, it is only available in PHP 5.4+ packages in Ubuntu as well.

Comment: i looked up upgrading from 5.3 to 5.4 and it fixed the problem, thank you!

Comment: Your link is dead!

Comment: @GauravDave Yes, it is. If you know a static URL to the changelog of the Debian PHP 5 package, feel free to edit.

Comment: I have php 5.6.30 installed, but still no php5enmod.

Comment: @Brent Are you using Debian or a derivative with official distribution packages?

Comment: @fkraiem Debian GNU/Linux 8.1 (jessie)

Comment: @Brent Please ask a new question on Unix SE (not here on Ask Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue and I found phpenmod command is in php-common package

As You know, php-common can be installed with this command:

```
apt-get install php-common
```

Comment: I am seeing `php-common is already the newest version (2:69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3).` but still it says 'php5enmod: command not found` ... Maybe I am missing something here?

Comment: I have the exact same problem

Comment: @user3768495 
please check is phpenmod file in /usr/sbin/

Comment: @JohnDee 
If you can't phpenmode in /usr/sbin , please enter output of this commands:
find /usr -name "php*mode"

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue with PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS after installing PHP using ondrej's PPA because PHP 5.6 is not available directly in current Ubuntu's repositories.

- See [that post for the installation](https://askubuntu.com/a/762161).

If `php5enmod` is still not found even if you already installed `php5.6` and `php-common` packages, try using `phpenmod` instead :

```sh
sudo phpenmod -v 5.6 mcrypt
```

- Where `-v 5.6` is specifying which PHP version you want to use.