# How can I downgrade from PHP 7 to PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apache2, php, 16.04, downgrade

I am trying to revert my PHP version to 5.6 from 7 and though I removed PHP 7 and then installed PHP 5.6 I still seem to be running version 7.

Is there a simple method for moving through PHP versions where apache, phpMyAdmin and co are configured appropriately?

A simple way to change the current version of PHP on the fly and even site by site would be great.

Comment: I appear to have 5.6 installed but all my php is rendering as text now.

Comment: what the output of `dpkg -l | grep php| awk '{print $2}' |tr "\n" " "` ?

Comment: dh-php libapache2-mod-php5 php-common php-json php-pear php-xml php5-cli php5-common php5-json php5-readline php5.6 php5.6-bz2 php5.6-cli php5.6-common php5.6-curl php5.6-dev php5.6-fpm php5.6-gd php5.6-json php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mysql php5.6-opcache php5.6-readline php7.0-common php7.0-json php7.0-xml pkg-php-tools

Comment: I see some php7 packages there remove them with `aptitude purge php7.0-common php7.0-json php7.0-xml ` also I want to know what you mean by `all my php is rendering as text now`

Comment: I've removed the php7 packages, but pages are still text. I seem to be going round in circles at the moment. I will update this page when I get it sorted.

Comment: it means you miss `libapache2-mod-php5.6` package ... see my answer below,  you don't need to remove `php7.0`

Comment: According to this link (https://askubuntu.com/a/306555/1516753) isn't it recommended to not install a previous version of PHP on a later version of OS? For example - Ubuntu 16.04 supports PHP 7+.

Answer (score 342, accepted):

**Update**
Today I got again problem with PHP 7 running despite I have disabled `php7.0` apache module: `phpinfo` was showing php 7 using fastCGI ...
... So if after you follow the below instructions you face this situation, you may need to disable the `proxy_fcgi` apache module:

```
sudo a2dismod proxy_fcgi proxy; sudo service apache2 restart
```

**1. Re-Install PHP 5.6**

What worked for me was this guide: http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2016/php-7-0-and-5-6-on-ubuntu

Actually is not required to remove `php7.0`, you can install php5.6 together  ( also because you will have dependency problem with `phpmyadmin` package that required php7.0)

Assuming `libapache2-mod-php` is a suitable way to enable PHP in Apache for you, you can proceed in this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

**2. Switch PHP version**:

- From php5.6 to php7.0:

  - Apache:

    ```
    sudo a2dismod php5.6 ; sudo a2enmod php7.0 ; sudo service apache2 restart
    ```
  - CLI:

    ```
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
    ```
- From php7.0 to php5.6:

  - Apache:

    ```
    sudo a2dismod php7.0 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6 ; sudo service apache2 restart
    ```
  - CLI:

    ```
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
    ```

Comment: I'll give this a go but are the two commands for switching versions supposed to be dismoding both versions of php each time?

Comment: you are right, thanks, I have fixed the commands :)

Comment: This appears to be the simplest way to deal with this. I like how you can toggle between versions of PHP too

Comment: @Postadelmaga It works to change the PHP version for the web apps. Thanks a lot! But the CLI still runs PHP7. Do you know how to switch that to PHP5.6 as well?

Comment: Best way to do it is to remove stock php packages, add Ondrej ppa and then install php7 and php5.6, remember you have phpenmod -v 5.6 to enable a php5.6 module and phpenmod -v 7.0 to enable a php 7.0 module, more info here https://disqus.com/home/discussion/serversforhackers/installing_php_7_with_memcached_servers_for_hackers/#comment-2590380342

Comment: Thx for your answer but changing from 5.6 to 7.0 doesn't seem to work, cause when I run `php -v` after restarting apache it still shows 5.6.21

Comment: The post saved my day.

Comment: @Daenu that because php -v is will show you the php cli version  ... the command suggested is for Apache  ... 
if you do a `phpinfo()` in a webpage  you will see the difference.

Comment: After writing that comment, I realised that too. Sry I'm a linux newbie.... Thx for that great answer!

Comment: I love this solution! Unfortunately, I have tried to do the same with phpbrew with no luck, and while I can run php7.0.6 perfectly and I can switch to 5.6 (there are no errors in the shell when I disable php7 and enable php5), apache seems to be broken with php5 and going to localhost simply doesn't work (unable to reach the website). If I switch back to php7, apache works again. I am not sure this is related to phpbrew, but still I can't use php5...

Comment: my guess is that you miss some `php5.6` module try to compare phpinfo between php5.6 and php7.0, check the apache log.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that apache with php5 is not working at all. So no phpinfo. When I switch to php7, boom: phpinfo works immediately. Also no errors in /var/log/apache2/error.log and no errors in the console when switching between the two versions. Don't know if I can look somewhere else...

Comment: For others, when using `php7.0` and `php5.6` in CLI without removing the native php7 install, `php5.6` won't occur as a prompt but will still work. You can even use `php5.6 -v` to check

Comment: @ToX82 try to uninstall any php (5.6/7) package and then follow the guide  from scratch

Comment: @Postadelmaga, it worked by uninstalling both php and apache and reinstalling from scratch. Thanks!

Comment: `sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/php5 /etc/alternatives/php` is what I needed.

Comment: Some folks need to stop using php5 (vs 5.6)

Comment: You are a god...

Comment: Beautiful! I just set up a brand new Debian 9 server on Linode and need to run PHP5 for an app I'm working on. These instructions were perfect as of October 2017   Thank you!

Comment: vote you for the clear state of **switching Apache and CLI**

Comment: **Warning**: Using this recipe trashed my entire PHP beyond repair.  Hours lost. Using ubuntu 14.04. Just a reminder to you guys: Do not blindly copy paste CLI oneliners without knowing what you are doing!

Comment: Great approach, helped me a lot.

Comment: According to this link (https://askubuntu.com/a/306555/1516753) isn't it recommended to not install a previous version of PHP on a later version of OS? For example - Ubuntu 16.04 supports PHP 7+.

Comment: @variable, look at [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04/766271#comment2577172_766271) in response to your identical comment.

Answer (score 52):

Ubuntu 16.04 comes with `php 7.0`, and some `php` applications might still fail with `php 7.0` .Therefore, in some cases, it might be sensible to have both `php 7.0` and `php 5.x`, so that you can choose which version to use for your needs at any time.

You can do so with:

```
xavi@computer# sudo su
root@computer# add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
root@computer# apt-get update
root@computer# apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php5.6-curl php5.6-gd php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-xml php5.6-xmlrpc
```

Installing both `php5.6 & php7.0` was clean in my case: no complain of issues, etc.

To switch from `php 5.6` to `php 7.0` you need to do two things:

```
# For php in web apps
sudo a2dismod php5.6 && sudo a2enmod php7.0 && sudo service apache2 restart
# For php-cli in the command line
sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/php7.0 /etc/alternatives/php
```

or from php7.0 to php5.6:

```
# For php in web apps
sudo a2dismod php7.0 && sudo a2enmod php5.6 && sudo service apache2 restart
# For php-cli in the command line
sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/php5.6 /etc/alternatives/php
```

You can also quickly check which yours is using by running php -v.

Comment: Use `sudo a2dismod php7.0  && sudo a2enmod php5.6 && sudo service apache2 restart` to make sure the following commands are only run when the before one succeeds. Proposed an edit to this answer.

Comment: This is the best answer for the ones willing to install both `php5.6` and  `php7.0` on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Worked like a charm. I wish I could upvote it multiple times.

Comment: According to this link (https://askubuntu.com/a/306555/1516753) isn't it recommended to not install a previous version of PHP on a later version of OS? For example - Ubuntu 16.04 supports PHP 7+.

Comment: Oh, @variable, wouldn't it be nice to stick with that recommendation! The problem is when you are at your job, and someone needs you to fix a web app that was written 5-6 years ago. Trying to rewrite everything in the latest `php` would take much longer than your boss is willing to pay you for. You have a family, so you don't have any time to "volunteer". That makes you grateful that people like Ondrej keep these PPAs up and running, so e.g. the Phalcon 5.4 that runs only on PHP 5.6 can be used, you rock it with the job you love, and your boss is happy with you.

Comment: @variable, having said all that, it is _always_ best to stick with the recommendation about the current software. A lot of times you can do so, but there will likely come times where it will be next to impossible. (You'll hear the word, legacy, and this kind of stuff will be useful.)

Answer (score 12):

Your question lacks important details, so I will answer more broadly.

Assuming you are using packages, there are some important details:

1. Apache2 can be configured to use either `apache2` SAPI using `libapache2-mod-php7.0` package or FPM SAPI using `php7.0-fpm` with `mod_proxy_fcgi`.
2. Ubuntu 16.04 has only PHP 7.0 in the repositories, you can use `ppa:ondrej/php` to add support for PHP 5.6 using similar naming scheme (e.g. `libapache2-mod-php5.6` or `php5.6-fpm`).
3. If you are using Apache2 SAPI (`libapache2-mod-php*`), you need to disable PHP 7.0 after you install `libapache2-mod-php5.6` by running `a2dismod php7.0` and enable PHP 5.6 by running `a2enmod php5.6`.
4. If you are using FPM SAPI (`php*-fpm`) then you need to change FPM unix socket from `/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` to `/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock`.
5. Please remember that for modules bundled with PHP (like MySQL) the naming convention is `phpX.Y-<ext>` (f.e. `php7.0-mysql` and `php5.6-mysql`), but for external PECL modules (f.e. APCu, mongodb, ...) it's just `php-<ext>` (f.e. `php-apcu`, `php-mongodb`).  I recommend running `apt-cache search php <ext>` on your system to search for correct package name before asking a questions on the Internet.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on how you would change the FPM unix socket?

Answer (score 6):

I think you should remove your php packages and install php5.6. You can proceed as follows:

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6
```

You can then check the version of your php to be sure. It is done as seen below:

```
php -v
```

Comment: I hope that the fact that you will remove your current php packages and install php freshly will be of great help to you.

Comment: You don't need to do grep-awk magic as all packaged depend on `php5-common`, so simply: `apt-get purge php5-common` will purge all php5 packages from your system.

Comment: According to this link (https://askubuntu.com/a/306555/1516753) isn't it recommended to not install a previous version of PHP on a later version of OS? For example - Ubuntu 16.04 supports PHP 7+.

Comment: @variable, look at [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04/766271#comment2577172_766271) in response to your identical comment.