# Ubuntu 16 php5.6 gd extension

Tags: 16.04, php

I'm running ubuntu 16 and I'm trying to install php5.6 extension GD.

I understand that php5.6 isn't available anymore in the default ubuntu repo's. I followed [How can I downgrade from PHP 7 to PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install php5.6 on my machine. But for my drupal site the GD php extension is required.

However it's not in the proposed repo. Can someone point me to the correct repo where I can still download/install the GD extension? Or an alternative method because I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is available from `ppa:ondrej/php`.

```
apt-get install php5.6-gd
```

will install GD for PHP 5.6

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd` worked for me. Thanks for the install pattern!