# Is it possible to write CodeIgniter 3.1.0 based application in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: php, 16.10

I am planning to move Ubuntu 16.10 from Windows. But before doing that I want to know: is it possible to write CodeIgniter 3.1.0 based application in Ubuntu 16.10. So far I know newer version of PHP is included in Ubuntu 16.10 ( may be I am wrong ).

Comment: Why did you think it's not possible/

Comment: @Anwar: I tried it in Ubuntu 16.04, where PHP version was 7 and it showed some error related to CI, and also face several problem to move from PHP 7 to older version. That's why again return to Windows OS. Now before moving to 16.10 I just want to know how to develop a CI 3.1.0 application us Ubuntu 16.10 if PHP v7 is built-in.

Comment: @Shimul, you can install apache and mysql from repo, and then [add php 5.6 to it](http://askubuntu.com/a/762161/260379).