# PHP 5.6 Broken on Installation of 16.04

Tags: php

I had two installations of PHP, PHP5.6 and PHP7.0, working as PHP-FPM/PHP_CGI packages in Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache2. I installed 16.04 thinking that it would not interfere with the third-party (ie: non-linux, non-ubuntu) software installations already in place, but I was obviously very much mistaken in that assumption. It seems that my PHP 5.6 installation was purposefully targeted by the installation and "nullified", but why? Security fixes will be made to PHP 5.6 until the end of 2018! http://php.net/supported-versions.php Why break all the work that I did in setting that up?

All the other posts that I have seen seem to want me to have PHP5.6 or the default PHP 7.0 on my server, but not both. Is there anyway I can have both installations working in 16.04, or do I have to (and can I) revert back to 14.04?

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Check here, it has instructions for you to keep both branches.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04/761735#761735