# Update from 16.04 to 18.04 also updated PHP 7.0 to 7.2 and this was unwanted

Tags: upgrade, php

I have updated my Ubuntu 16.04 server to 18.04. The upgrade script (do-release-upgrade) worked correctly except that it also updaded PHP7.0 to PHP7.2 without asking. The problem is that I make use of PHP scripts not compatibles with PHP7.2 and I don't want to upgrade PHP now.

Since I have done an upgrade test on a VMWare virtual machine, I can easily restart the whole process.

But how to prevent the upgrade script from updating PHP7.0 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Upgrading ALL the software on your system is exactly what `do-release-upgrade` is supposed to do; you are describing expected behavior. Preventing elements of 18.04 from being installed is possible ([apt-pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto)), but is untested and may have quite unexpected results. Advice: Remain upon 16.04 until you are ready for a new version of PHP that matches 18.04 or 20.04.

Comment: I've found this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/862183/update-from-14-04-to-16-04-php-version?rq=1 In the answer, there are solutions to hold package update. this was for upgrade from version 14 to 16. Would this work for upgrade from 16 to 18?

Comment: In theory, yes, it should work just at well as apt-pinning. Remember that you are testing, and may get unexpected results.