# PHP Code displays in browser

Tags: apache2, php

I make a fresh install of LAMP components on Ubuntu.
The following installations are done

```
apt-get install php
apt-get install php-mysql
apt-get install mysql-server
apt-get install apache2
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
apt-get install dolibarr
apt-get install php7.0 php5.6 php5.6-mysql php-gettext php5.6-mbstring php-xdebug libapache2-mod-php5.6 libapache2-mod-php7.0
apt-get install python-software-properties pkg-config software-properties-common
```

When I access `<MyIP>/dolibarr/htdocs`, I get the PHP code displayed and not executed.

When I access `<MyIP>/test.php`, I get the PHP code below executed and PHP info displayed:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Both this test.php and [Dolibarr](https://wiki.dolibarr.org/index.php/Installation_-_Upgrade#With_DoliDeb_.28Debian_or_Ubuntu_.deb_package.29) are placed in `/var/www`

Apache root dir is set in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www
```

Because I wanted to make sure PHP version was not implied, I tried [this tuto](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04) and swiched between PHP 7.0 and PHP 5.6.

I'm stuck here.
Any idea please folks ?

Comment: I don't think you need `htdocs` in Ubuntu, make `dolibarr` root by placing __all files and folders__ of `htdocs` in `/var/www/dolibarr` then from browser do `<MyIP>/dolibarr/index.php`

Comment: How do we set "solved"?

Comment: I need to post it as an answer then you select it as solved, i'll do that now.

Comment: Just posted the answer you can accept it by clicking the button on the left of the answer.

Comment: Oh great, have a nice day @George :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu the default `apache` directory is `/var/www` or `/var/www/html` not `htdocs` like in `Windows` so to fix your issue do:

1. make `dolibarr` root by placing **all files and folders** of `htdocs` in `/var/www/dolibarr`
2. Then from browser do `<MyIP>/dolibarr/index.php`