# How can I upgrade my PHP version?

Tags: package-management, php

I installed PHP 5.6 and when I run `php -v` it shows

```
PHP 5.6.30-7+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (cli)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

but when I get `phpinfo();` in index file show in header:

```
PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26
```

How can upgrade my php version?

Comment: To what version will you want to upgrade?

Comment: i want 5.6 version

Comment: Probably your PHP apache module is still at version 5.3; please edit your question to add the output of `dpkg -l | grep libapache2-mod-php`.

Comment: And please also disregard the current answers; they are probably wrong.

Comment: @fkraim that line show:  `ii  libapache2-mod-php5              5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26                    server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open apache config:
   `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
2. At the end of the file add the following: 
   `<IfModule php5_module>
       PHPIniDir "/etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini"
   </IfModule>`
3. Restart apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`

UPDATE: if that didn't work, try the following in a terminal: 
1. Make sure php 5.3 module is installed: 
`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5.6` 
2. Disable 5.3 and enable 5.6: 
`sudo a2dismod php5.3 && sudo a2enmod php5.6 && sudo service apache2 restart`

With attribution to [Grayson Kent](https://askubuntu.com/users/668095/grayson-kent), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/619969/restarting-apache-2-broke-website)

Comment: the first solution didn't work and the second solution didn't work too. and show that error :ERROR: Module php7.0 does not exist!
ERROR: Module php5.6 does not exist!

Comment: Please retry the updated second solution

Comment: Generally this answer is on the right track though the exact configuration may vary.  The package you need for apache2 is different to the CLI version.  For example libapache2-mod-phpVER versus php-VER for the CLI. Other setups are also possible using suphp, fastcgi, etc.

Comment: @lamino i get this `ERROR: Module php5.3 does not exist!
ERROR: Module php5.6 does not exist!`
 too!!!

Comment: Maybe the apache2 module is different or doesn't exist for php5.3. I have no way of knowing that since this version is deprecated. There's also a slight chance purging php5.3* could solve this problem.