# Wordpress Install on Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.04 weird PHP error

Tags: 16.04, mysql, php, nginx, wordpress

Sorry if there a super simple solution to this but I'm stumped after following the other questions here.

I get the following error when visiting one of the websites hosted on my server

`Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.`

This in Wordpress

Here is my PHP version:

```
PHP 7.1.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jul  7 2017 09:41:45) ( NTS ) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.1.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

But running things like:
`sudo apt-get install php-mysql`

Say its already installed.

This is my NGINX config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/omitted.me/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_name omitted.me www.omitted.me;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

}

What am i doing wrong or where can I look to find out what's going on here?

**Updated - Fix**
Long story short the issue was with my PHP environment, I literally just wiped and refreshed:
[How can I downgrade from PHP 7 to PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Restart the server with `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work but I found a fix, I'll amend the questions to my solution

Comment: @iLC, please answer your own question so others may benefit.